# Uniforms: Creating custom field

Tags: reactjs, meteor, semantic-ui, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I have the following Simple Schema defined:

```js
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

export const Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");

export const CommentsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  comments: Array,
  "comments.$": Object,
  "comments.$.author": String
  "comments.$.text": String
})
```

And I have a component with `AutoForm` to view/edit this comments array:

```js
import {ErrorsField, SubmitField, ListField} from "uniforms-semantic";
import AutoForm from 'uniforms-semantic/AutoForm';

<AutoForm schema={CommentsSchema} onSubmit={comments => this.updateRequest(comments)} model={this.props.comments}>
  <ListField name={"comments"}/>
  <ErrorsField/>
  <SubmitField/>
</AutoForm>
```

`this.updateRequest(...)` is a function that calls Meteor backend function that updates Mongo collection.

I would like to customize `ListField` so that for each comment the `"comments.$.text"` TextField is displayed as a bigger text box with newlines allowed.

It's currently just a single line string:[image: Current ListField]

I considered rewriting a custom version of `ListField` but that seemed unnecessarily complicated for a small change like that. What is the best way to do add small customization like this using uniforms API?

Comment: Any reason you can't just do it with CSS?

Comment: @ZackNewsham `TextField` that is generated by default for Strings doesn't allow newlines AFAIK, so I doubt that simply editing CSS would work.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, my appologies. Thought it was about styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs, it appears you can specify the inner workings of ListField. This is untested, but I would guess something along these lines:

```js
<ListField name="comments">
    <ListItemField name="$">
        <NestField name="">
            <TextField name="author" />
             <LongTextField name="text" />
        </NestField>
    </ListItemField>
</ListField>
```

https://github.com/vazco/uniforms/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md#props-propagation

Comment: I saw the section you referred to, but for some reason thought it doesn't apply in my case and went on looking for more complicated solution... This snippet works great for me!